# Silverlight DataGrid adding button on Header

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a DataGrid as rowDetailTemplate. in this grid I'd like to add a button on header. I made the following XAML code

```
                          <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn   >
                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Content="Row" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                         <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Content="Del"></Button>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Everything works correctly but the this column header. I am getting `System.Windows.DataTemplate`  instead of the button. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the way by compiling some answers. the following will add a template column with header-Body containing controls:

```
     <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn >
          <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
              <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                  <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                  <Button Content="Row" />
                             </DataTemplate>
                         </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
              </Style>
          </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
          <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <Button Content="Del"  ></Button>
              </DataTemplate>
          </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below link which will help you
[Button in DataGrid header](http://www.exploresilverlight.com/2012/08/adding-button-in-datagrid-header-in.html)

Cheers!
Vinod

Comment: Thanks Vinod, but I don't want use style. I want to just add a template header, and CellTemplate, and why my code is not working. thanks anyway.